# Xcode undefined symbols for architecture

Tags: xcode

Just started to teach OOP and have a weird error in my program, that looks like in my example. I'm using XCode and receive stange error :

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  "Foo::Foo()", referenced

```
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo();
        ~Foo();
        Foo(const Foo& f2);
        Foo(int data);
        Foo& operator =(const Foo& f2);
    protected:
        int m_Data;
};

Foo::Foo(int data)
{
    m_Data = data;
    cout << "constr1" << endl;
}

Foo::Foo(const Foo& f2)
{
    m_Data = f2.m_Data;
    cout << "constr2" << endl;
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    cout << " destructor";
}

Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo& f2)
{
    m_Data = f2.m_Data;
    cout << "prisvaivanie" << endl;
    return *this;
}

Foo test(Foo arg)
{
    return arg;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Foo f1(1);
    Foo f2(f1);
    Foo f3 = f1;
    Foo f4;
    f4 = f1;
    Foo f5 = test(f1);
    return 0;
}
```

What can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare a constructor that takes no parameters but don't define one and `Foo f4;` needs it.

Comment: Thanks, i understand now. Is there any possibilities to associate Foo::Foo() with default constructor?

Comment: You could get rid of `Foo();` and change the `int` constructor to something like `Foo(int data = 0);`, modified depending on what you actually want `m_Data` to be as a default.

Comment: (Note that this has nothing to do with "Xcode", in spite of your tag, and is really just general C++.)